# Poster Presentation at a Doctoral Training event

Tags: phd, conference, poster

I am attending an international doctoral training event in an area of physics that matches the area of my PhD. We have been asked to produce a poster for the event, which mentions including any results you have or simply just a poster on your project itself.

I was wondering if anyone has been through similar to this and has any advice on how to construct a suitable poster for such an event that is based just on a project rather than actual results that have been obtained.

Comment: The answer correctly focuses on content of the poster.  For help on the form, a search on "preparing scientific posters" finds a lot.  Be sure to check the work of Colin Purrington for templates in addition to advice.

Answer (score 1):

When you say project, do you mean NSF (or similar) funded project?  Then make a poster based on the solicitation you send to NSF. Otherwise, imagine that you want to persuade a funding agency to give you money. You will have to explain what you are going to do and why it is interesting. That's what your poster is about.

You should be able to find old posters lying or hanging around to give you some idea how they work. Usually, posters try to convey information in too much detail and are therefore hard to read. A good poster makes it easy to see (not at one glance but within a few seconds) where the project is located in the spectrum of your discipline. In the case of a project you need to tell what it is and why it is important. You also need to say how it is going to be attacked. Do not assume that viewers know too much about your field, but do not assume either that you need to explain electromagnetism either. If you can, a good illustration spares many words.